# Multi cross-filtering in Vega-Lite

Tags: vega-lite

I want to set up a dashboard with three cross-filters.

Desired outcome: Selecting a single month should filter the selected month and retain the filter by the other two dimensions (all project types and owners). If you select from two filters, it would not need all the items manually selected from the third filter.

Any ideas on achieving the desired outcome or direction to go next would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried setting the following "filter" condition on Vega-Lite, but doesn't behave as I'd expect.

Vega-Lite:

```
  "transform": [
                    {
                        "filter": {
                            "selection": {
                                "and": [
                                        "pTypeSelection",
                                        "monthSelection",
                                        "tltSelection"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
```

[Start State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swiem.png)

This is the dashboard before anything is selected.

Selecting one month should be filtering by all project types and owners.

[Selecting Only month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67x5p.png)

Selecting months shows nothing, because the "and" condition is not met. "Or" does not do what I want (which is "and"-based cross-filtering).

[Selecting month and project type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvOFJ.png)

Selecting project types don't show anything either until...

[Selecting from all 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVfhh.png)

I select something from all three filters, at which point the "and" condition is met.

[Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqjPj.png)

This is how it should behave if just a month is selected

This is the auto-generated filter expression. I have attempted modifying it to achieve my goal no avail.

Vega:

```
"type": "filter",
"expr": "!(length(data(\"pTypeSelection_store\")) || length(data(\"monthSelection_store\")) || length(data(\"tltSelection_store\"))) || ((vlSelectionTest(\"pTypeSelection_store\", datum)) && (vlSelectionTest(\"monthSelection_store\", datum)) && (vlSelectionTest(\"tltSelection_store\", datum)))"
```

Edit:
Here is the example using 2 filters: [example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABBYEQCQM4GMAWBTAtgQygLmkgLvgA5zYD0ZAbigOYYB0NAlvkgK4BG9TA9mYqkxVaGALQAbFiioBmegCs4PAHZQANOEhQAJhnxZcoSMehsATuJzRd+-ij35xKUQHd7rFGfoI4lKJogAXw1jKCQEFQQ9KwBtAJMjEySoSgjlKPxY+KSkxJz8rXwzDGU4ADMeMzQsgtqE7LrGqDKmcXxPKzzG7tC4FCcEfF5VQwae8egS7RqJ2dqoNz1UMwBlfpRB4fUxud2dPRQ1gaGVf13ZgF0d8+NA6927m8hH3YuQvZR0nm0mZRpO+49KAADwBT2SLX601w+3a23BJig+AAnkQUFYoJUfsoMJZ3giIFAMMCmHAwQTkkNHOiYQARA7wimI8QYDj9ACCfycVlEADYAAyA2YvJ7BIVNZHkinNJhQjEuX7TfEEpGomnQACObBKVL0TGojOlxNJUqZhKp3JhAHVFWcmSKbmKEVAIuJKqabjK5TDFh4zFAwMrPU4aJ9oWAyri+mBxXUHRMnXsWciOrg4gius6FdpWFYBfyg+CwigmDQCFYZABWAuxoGYMwAawxHAw-trBXj4yuCcLtUz4wWTBzSDz-Jr52LpfLuAATOO9vWmzCW-7e90oH1jltRs6bId1ptTjumaq0Ri0Gw2kxDSrPhFsTQyWn2xMQXaKd3wZ2eom5lA798vz-MeTxviBKpDGgKAAKrKCwGIpq2N7OpC4jhrC6JrhOKJnjCWK-LiyFFsaT5gP20oWuqUD0nCWFFiybLiJyNCWmAgpmt+wp0UCrruuBzppD8JwjGRL4DiGYZWJG4h9NxnqbhswkYnuRyKVscnYWqGLKDwaAEZYYm1L+KoSco4bSbJhkFCkuJsFRkhlvgNDFJKGkDjhVE6XpOIGQinGNP5OSBRAn5JMZxjkYi2a5rO87zKgU6ZLFcXWYuzZIXJSIsKxUBWu4yxEckCmHiJkX5As+WeKpJUeu5WkwheV6FeuAEPqR6ZFpKVmhd0wVgOFOT-l8D61fMkr8QOqHob6BVuZS9XQF5+nNU0JGjbMWXUhiK0DpUsrKEl0BmIl77Cu2A3zLx-oTTxKhCduonOqZ5lRigc3WcVSk+pVqwHkp73lR52m6ctAODVN8o-adPZWTZ4h2RiDkEM5GCubDQMwktPk7fMz1Sa951CpxDpXIEQA)

Comment: It's very hard to answer this question as written because you don't include a full example with data and code (even if your data cannot be shared, it's useful to provide an example built on a similar dataset). For example, I have no idea how you've defined your selectors or which sub-charts you've attached them to.

Comment: @jakevdp I have added an example using the Vega-Lite online editor